# How to configure a writable directory on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an PHP application a AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
The base app is working, but I doesn't get a configured writable directory for the app
When I try to create a temporary file with the following code:

```
$CACHEFilePath = \Yii::$app->runtimePath . $model->reportpath;
$tempfile = tempnam($CACHEFilePath, 'charts') . '.png';
```

I'm getting the following error :

> tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory

Even  I force the directory to be /tmp, the error stay the same. I also tried to force the upload_tmp_dir from php.ini with  Environment properties

Please advice

Comment: you must be using `php7`, did you tried to set in `php.ini` the `upload_tmp_dir = PATH/TO/TMPDIR`? and did you verify if those settings are updated?

Answer (score 0):

Well I change my code like follow :

```
$CACHEFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . $this->reportpath;
```

with the `upload_tmp_dir=/tmp` in the php.ini